# String.format to change a decimal variable depending on CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

I need to change the format of variable, depending on CurrentCulture

Variable is a Decimal

This is my current change statement :

```
 string auxst = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "#,##0.00", variable);
```

I need to know what to put in the second parameter so that this happens:

```
Variable = 150.465,1242345

If CurrentCulture is "es ES"(spain) ->  auxst = "150.465,1242345"

If CUrrentCulture is "en EN" ->  auxst = "150,465.1242345"
```

Thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you use CurrentCulture, do not specify it.

You should use Decimal.ToString():

```
Decimal variable = 15465.1242345M;
string auxst = variable.ToString("N");
```

Comment: Please *do* specify it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475383/is-cultureinfo-currentculture-really-necessary-in-string-format

Comment: You _can_ for documentation purposes only, as the link you provide says.

Comment: Not specifying it is meant to document that you haven't thought about it. Specifying it *documents* you *have* thought about it. So as you have thought about it and using CurrentCulture is a choice, not an oversight, you should document it.

Comment: Not specifying it doesn't mean you haven't thought about it. It just means you don't know if the developer has thought about it or not. This discussion is just politic. :-)

But we do not care as it doesn't change much the answer for PruebasDev.
The point is use "N" formatter. :-)

Comment: Indeed. So your advice should not be "do not specify", because you *have* thought about it and therefor *should* document that you did.